# Returning Nth line from multiple files

Tags: awk, git-bash

Given a folder with multiple .csv files, I want to return the Nth line from each file and write to a new file.

For a single file, I use

```
    awk 'NR==5' file.csv
```

For multiple files, I figured

```
    ls *.csv | xargs awk 'NR==5'
```

...however that only returns the 5th line from the first file in the list.

Thanks!

Comment: You want `FNR == 5` instead: that's the record number of the current file. `NR` is the record number of all records seen in the input stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you(GNU `awk` should help I believe):

```
awk 'FNR==5{print;nextfile}' *.csv
```

In case you need to take output into a single out file then append `> output_file` at last of above command too.

***Explanation:***

`FNR==5`: Checking here if line number is 5th for current Input_file then do actions mentioned after it.

`{print;}`: `print` is `awk` out of the box keyword which prints the current line so it will print the 5th line only.

`nextfile`: as by name itself it is clear that `nextfile` will skip all the lines in current Input_file(since I have given *.csv in end so it means it will pass all csv files to `awk` 1 by 1) it will save time for us since we DO NOT want to read the entries Input_file we needed only 5th line and we got it.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a ton - any chance you could explain why that did exactly what I needed it to do?

Comment: @MikeeeeeeeyC, added explanation too now, let me know if that helps you.

Comment: Perfect - totally tracking now, thanks again for your help!